# Get slot of block by hash

Tags: go-ethereum, prysm

I am running a devnet with Geth as the execution client and Prysm as the consensus client.

I am querying the clients using their REST API accordingly. I want to be able to know in which slot a block, identified by its hash, was proposed in.

The endpoints `/eth/v1/beacon/headers/{block_id}` and `/eth/v2/beacon/blocks/{block_id}` do not seem to help as the `block_id` they require (as noted [in the documentation](https://ethereum.github.io/beacon-APIs/#/Beacon/getBlockV2)) `hex encoded blockRoot with 0x prefix`, which is not the block hash or any other identifying hash in the block (at least not that I found in my testing).

Querying all the slots and then reverse-mapping them to blocks is not a viable solution as the number of slots in my context is not bounded (relative to the number of blocks in the canonical chain).

If so, is there any other method of getting the slot a block was proposed at based on the block's hash?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I also need a way to get the slot number given the block number or block hash.

Comment: My solution was to iterate over the slots, and for each one to check if it has a block on the chain with the corresponding slot index. Then, to check the slot of the `i`th block, I have a while loop that continues until I find `i` slots with blocks in them. I have verified that this method is correct and it worked well for me. Hope this helps.